# AndroidManfest File in Flutter has Errors

Tags: flutter, dart

My phone does not reach the Internet in the Flutter application. I think it's because of this file. Is this a correct xml File?

[image: main/AndroidManifest.xml]

Comment: Please post logs for when you try to do any network activity and yes!, this is the correct file.

Comment: is it a problem that so many words are marked red? Where can I see the logs?

Comment: No, its not an error. Your IDE (Android Studio) is trying to read anything specific to Flutter, and Manifest is related to "Android", so it thinks its an error. If you open the android folder only inside the android studio, you will see that the error is gone. 

You can see logs in the "Run" tab at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a network security config in your manifest.
You have to set it in order to access specific urls from your app

Add this line inside application tag in your manifest

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and create a file app\src\main\res\network_security_config.xml

This is an example of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://www.google.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">facebook.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get the error that " AAPT: error: resource xml/network_security_config (aka de.myracledesign.network_request:xml/network_security_config) not found. " Although I put it in the app/src/main/res/network_security/config.xml place

Comment: I created a directory 'xml' at app\src\main\res and put the network_security_config.xml file in there now there is no mistake anymore. But still no Intenet connection